# Is there a way to find the exact number?

Tags: java, math

There are two places that sell bicycles and equipment. One of them has a starting price on 150 (don't mind the unit) and for each day you rent the bike it'll cost 13.
The other place has a starting price of 200 with a rate of 10 (units per day).

So here's the qustion. at what price does the two of them collide?

i tried to solve this, but because of my limited experience with programming, I  couldn't find the EXACT number.
The result i got was 370, but when i put it in geogebra (a simple math program) its result was 366,66.

```
public class Challenges{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int StartPrice1 = 200;
        int StartPrice2 = 150;

        int hk1 = 10;
        int hk2 = 13;

        boolean running = true;
        while(running){
            if(StartPrice1 <= StartPrice2){
                System.out.println(StartPrice1);
                break;
            } else{
                StartPrice1+=hk1;
                StartPrice2+=hk2;


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your answer is going to be `366.66`, you obviously shouldn't be using integers

Comment: If the answer is 366.66, and days aren't fractures, then they will never collide. (assuming the amount of days for each rent is the same.)

Comment: maybe, just maybe, that instead of 13 it should have been 15 (units per day) .... (despite then resulting in an obvious result)

Answer (score 0):

Your program is correct if you cannot rent the bike for a fraction of the day.

**geogebra answer:**
Assume x = number of days that it takes for the costs to meet.

```
200 + 10x <= 150 + 13x
```

Solving for x; you get x = 16.667 (after rounding). Thus, the answer is 200 + 10 * 16.67 = 366.67

Answer (score 0):

## Will the 2 shops ever cost the same?

```
| Day Number | Shop 1 | Shop 2 |
|           0|     150|     200|
|           1|     163|     210|
|           2|     176|     220|
|           3|     189|     230|
|           4|     202|     240|
|           5|     215|     250|
|           6|     228|     260|
|           7|     241|     270|
|           8|     254|     280|
|           9|     267|     290|
|          10|     280|     300|
|          11|     293|     310|
|          12|     306|     320|
|          13|     319|     330|
|          14|     332|     340|
|          15|     345|     350|
|          16|     358|     360|
|          17|     371|     370|
|          18|     384|     380|
|          19|     397|     390|
|          20|     410|     400|
```

As you can see, there is no day when the 2 shops cost the same, on day 16 shop 1 costs 358 and shop 2 costs 360, and on day 17 shop 1 costs 371 and shop 2 costs 370.

## What does it mean for the 2 shops prices to 'collide'

If your definition of collide is to swap prices, then your program is correct. Geogebra gave you the point in the day where the 2 shops have the same price, but you will never pay for part of a day, so this answer is unlikely to be a useful one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update counter to update price each second, not each day to improve accuracy, see the results below (I put some explanations in the comments to proper lines as well as at the end of this answer to make it clear what is going on it this code):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double StartPrice1 = 200;
    double StartPrice2 = 150;

    double hk1 = 10;
    double hk1StepPerSecond = hk1 / 86400; // 86400 seconds are in 24 hours :-)

    double hk2 = 13;
    double hk2StepPerSecond = hk2 / 86400;

    double days = 0; // to show how many days needed to collide
    boolean running = true;

    while(running){
        if(StartPrice1 <= StartPrice2){
            System.out.println("Price when collision has been detected: " + StartPrice1);
            break;
        } else{
            StartPrice1+=hk1StepPerSecond; // price increased after 1 second - not 1 day to improve accuracy
            StartPrice2+=hk2StepPerSecond; // price increased after 1 second - not 1 day to improve accuracy
            days = days + 1; // incrementing number of days
        }
    }
    System.out.println("How many days to detect collision: " + days / 86400); // just to print number of days to collide
    System.out.println("How many seconds to detect collision: " + days);
}
```

Output you get:

```
Price when collision has been detected: 366.6667824049821
How many days to detect collision: 16.66667824074074
How many seconds to detect collision: 1440001.0 // Collision detected after 16 days, 16 hours and 1 second
```

### Explanation:

The result you get from your code seems to be not that bad, you lose a bit of accuracy - you can think of it as you check the prices at 12:00 AM every day, and on day, when `StartPrice1` is equal to 370, for the first time it is less than `StartPrice2` - but equation of StartPrice1 and StartPrice2 didn't happen exactly at 12:00 - it happened few hours earlier, but your code doesn't have a proper accuracy to check every second, or even fractions of seconds, it simply check value at 12:00. I hope it is more understandable for you, I tried to improve accuracy of your code from 1 day to one second.

Comment: Thank you alot:) the fact that you changed it to seconds makes sense to me now. Big help.

Comment: @RasmusAndersen Glad that I could help :-) If you think that this answer is helpful, you might want to consider upvoting it or ticking it as the accepted one if you think that it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is using integers while your answer is not a guaranteed whole number. And your algorithm is attempting to calculate when the starting price of the second store becomes equal (**or more expensive than**) the first. Your question wants to know when they are exactly equal.

By incrementing in whole days, that's not a guarantee, since the price may become equal in the middle of a day.  You would need to find out what's the difference in days of the amount you've gone over, then add back to the previous iteration how much it costs for a partial day at those rates

Rather than go that approach, though, computer pograms work really well with matrix operations, so model the problem as matrix algebra. Let p be the final price, d be the days. You're solving for p.

```
13d - p = -150
10d - p = -200
```

[Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/linear.html) can help you solve that. Section 3.4

Or you can use plain linear algebra.  Let `d` be the number of days, find when the prices are equal

```
13d + 150 = 10d + 200  
13d = 10d + 50
3d = 50
d = 50/3
```

Plug `d` back to the one side of the equation to find the price